# Merge data from different table with count

Tags: r, merge, plyr

I have two different tables like the following (First table have section information, second table has crash information. First table has all section information, some of the sections doesn't have any crash occurrence for which there's no crash information on those sections in the second table. The merge table is required to count total crashes. If there's no crash, the section will require to plug in zero values.):

```
a <- structure(list(CSECT = c("001-01", "001-01", "001-01", "001-04", "001-01", "001-01", "001-02", "001-02", "001-03", "001-04"), 
From = c("0", "1", "3", "4", "5", "7", "8", "1", "2.2", "3.4"), 
To = c("1", "3", "4", "5", "6", "8", "9", "2.2", "3.4", "4.5")),
.Names = c("CSECT", "From", "To"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")
a

  CSECT    From  To
1  001-01    0   1
2  001-01    1   3
3  001-01    3   4
4  001-04    4   5
5  001-01    5   6
6  001-01    7   8
7  001-02    8   9
8  001-02    1 2.2
9  001-03  2.2 3.4
10 001-04  3.4 4.5

b <- structure(list(CSECT = c("001-01", "001-01", "001-01", "001-01", "001-01", "001-01", "001-01", "001-01", "001-01", "001-01",
"001-02", "001-02","001-02","001-02","001-02","001-02","001-02"), 
From = c("0", "0", "0", "0", "1", "1", "3", "3", "3", "3", "8", "8", "8", "8","1", "1", "1"), 
To = c("1", "1", "1", "1", "3", "3", "4", "4", "4", "4", "9", "9", "9", "9", "2.2", "2.2", "2.2"), 
CrashID = c("3409", "3410", "6790", "1100", "1200", "5609", "6730", "1220", "1234", "1239",
"4409", "5610", "6794", "1123", "1245", "5634", "6732")),
.Names = c("CSECT", "From", "To", "CrashID"), row.names = c(NA, -17L), class = "data.frame")
b

   CSECT   From  To CrashID
1  001-01    0   1    3409
2  001-01    0   1    3410
3  001-01    0   1    6790
4  001-01    0   1    1100
5  001-01    1   3    1200
6  001-01    1   3    5609
7  001-01    3   4    6730
8  001-01    3   4    1220
9  001-01    3   4    1234
10 001-01    3   4    1239
11 001-02    8   9    4409
12 001-02    8   9    5610
13 001-02    8   9    6794
14 001-02    8   9    1123
15 001-02    1 2.2    1245
16 001-02    1 2.2    5634
17 001-02    1 2.2    6732
```

I like to merge the data like following:

```
CSECT   From    To  Count
001-01    0     1       4
001-01    1     3       2
001-01    3     4       4
001-04    4     5       0
001-01    5     6       0
001-01    7     8       0
001-02    8     9       4
001-02    1     2.2     3
001-03  2.2     3.4     0
001-04  3.4     4.5     0
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 cc <- by( b[-(1:3)], b[1:3], function(x) list( 
    Total =length(x$CrashID),   
    Fatal =sum(x$Severity=="Fatal"),  
    Severe=sum(x$Severity=="Severe"),  
    PDO=sum(x$Severity=="PDO") ) ,
    simplify=FALSE)
 dd <- cbind(unique(b[1:3]), do.call(rbind, cc) )
 ee < -merge(a, dd, all.x=TRUE)
 ee[ is.na(ee) ] <- 0
 ee
#-----------

    CSECT From  To AADT Total Fatal Severe PDO
1  001-01    0   1 1100     4     1      0   3
2  001-01    1   3 1200     3     0      0   3
3  001-01    3   4  890     2     0      0   2
4  001-01    5   6 2000     0     0      0   0
5  001-01    7   8 5000     0     0      0   0
6  001-02    1 2.2 2000     4     0      0   4
7  001-02    8   9 6700     4     1      1   2
8  001-03  2.2 3.4 3000     0     0      0   0
9  001-04  3.4 4.5 1230     0     0      0   0
10 001-04    4   5 1000     0     0      0   0
```